# Moving from WCF RIA Beta to RC: best practices?

Tags: c#, wcf-ria-services

I have an existing WCF RIA project built on the Release Candidate; I'm now moving to the Release version & have discovered many changes.  [David Scruggs](http://blogs.msdn.com/dscruggs/about.aspx) made [the following comment on his (MSDN) blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/dscruggs/archive/2010/03/16/silverlight-4-ria-breaking-changes.aspx):

> "If you’ve written anything in
>   SIlverlight 4 RIA Services, you’ll
>   need to rewrite it.  There has been a
>   lot of refactoring and namespace
>   moves."

Having made a brief attempt to compile the old solution with the new RIA framework I'm inclined to agree.  My current plan is to:

- remove the Silverlight Business Application projects from the Solution
- rebuild the EF4 items from the database
- create a new Silverlight Business Application project
- re-add the files (XAML, CS) from the old Silverlight Business Application project

Does this sound like a reasonable approach?  I think it's cleaner than trying to manually alter the existing project.

Comment: you mean "moving from beta to RC", aren't you?

Comment: Yup.  Had RC -> RTM on the brain after performing that particular upgrade on VS and TFS.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project started with a Silverlight Business Application then yes, that is a decent way to go about it.

There are quite a few changes in that template that your work will depend on, so having the base code working again makes it easier to do the minor tweaks needed. For me it was mostly namespaces, but having all of the Login controls throwing a fit over namespaces and undefined type etc, makes it feel like more of a problem than it is.

Comment: You're right.  I actually tried the other way first (manually fixing up the generated code) following some advice on the SL forum.  Wasted a day that way.  It only took a few hours this morning to redo from scratch, re-adding our code around a new generated skeleton.